# Adjust y axis when using parallel_coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

I'm working on plotting some data with pandas in the form of parallel coordinates, and I'm not too sure how to go about setting the y-axis scaling.

here is my code:

```
def show_means(df: pd.DataFrame):
plt.figure('9D-parallel_coordinates')
plt.title('continents & features')
parallel_coordinates(df,'continent', color=['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow','orange','black'])
plt.show()
```

and I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4rEp.png)

as shown in the graph, the value of "tempo" is way more than others. I want to scale all features values between 0 and 1 and get a line chart. How could I do that? Also, I want to change exegesis to vertical that readers can understand it easier.

this is my data frame:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OFcU.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To normalize your values between 0 and 1, you have multiple choices. One of them could be (MinMaxScaler): the lowest value of each column is 0 and the highest value is 1:

```
df = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

To have vertically labels, use `df.plot(rot=90)`

Comment: First of all Thanks! But when I use the de.plot it does not only rotate the labels but also adds new lines to the graph, which I don't need. how do I solve it?

Comment: I don't know what the function `parallel_coordinates` does?

Comment: Nvm, I figured out how to rotate labels. plt.xticks(rotation=90)